# Do GCP logs contain metric data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I need to fetch metric data through logs. Is this possible?

Do GCP logs contain metric data? If they do, then how to extract it?

Is there any way to enable the logging (with metrics) to keep the metric data (shown in Stackdriver)?

Comment: Do you want to log YOUR business metric and then use it (agg, avg, sum,...) ?

Comment: I dont want to use stackdriver api. Want to disable stackdriver monitoring apis and fetch the metrics using logs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to fetch metric data through logs. Is this possible?

- Yes!

> Do GCP logs contain metric data? If they do, then how to extract it?

- It depends on the logs in question, but in general, yes - some logs may contain numeric values you could use for metrics.

> Is there any way to enable the logging (with metrics) to keep the metric data (shown in Stackdriver)?

- You can use Log-Based Metrics to extract numeric values from logs and convert them to metrics.
  https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/
- You should also take a look at this, which is somewhat related to what you're asking:
  https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/custom-metrics-agent

Comment: Yuri has many excellent videos on Stackdriver on YouTube. He is Google's "Stack Doctor": https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=google+cloud+stack+doctor

Comment: Thank you, John - I appreciate the promotion :)

Comment: I need to fetch metrics of PUB/SUB or Dataflow  .
ex : dataflow.googleapis.com/job/billable_shuffle_data_processed. 

My requirement is to get all metrics that shown in stackdriver using logs.

I can fetch the metrics from stackdriver (Time series metrics) but am I able to get all those metics from logs without using stackdriver.

Right now, log-based metrics only contains data related to audit of application but not the stats of that application/service .

Comment: ex. I have created a topic in pub/sub and a subscriber , then I have published the message , logs generated but only for creation of topic/subscriber , but 
pubsub.googleapis.com/subscription/ack_message_count , data is not there .
So these logs can contains these metric data or not

Comment: No, GCP platform metrics aren't logged in the way you're describing.  I'm interested in your use case, though - why isn't using the Monitoring API sufficient, and why do you need these values in logs?

Comment: actually, We want to fetch metrics without enabling stackdriver apis .

Comment: Yep - I understand that - I'd like to know why.

Comment: Because I want to create an agentless environment where I can push logs into pub/sub and then publish those logs to all subscriber. Right now, My agent is requesting to stackdriver for the metrics. 
Is it possible to push metric data into pub/sub and then this publish the data to all the subscriber on a definite interval?

Comment: Sure, you could push messages that contain a numeric metric value to PubSub and then consume those somewhere else if you think that'd address your goal.